# Как правильно запрашивать переменную из сервлета в файл jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Мне просто нужно передать строку из сервлета в jsp, чтобы по адресу вывести картинку. Форма под картинку выводится, но поле пустое. Как правильно отправлять картинку на сайт?

jsp

```
<div>
      <%
      out.print("<img src="+request.getAttribute("image1").toString()+"width='270' height='270'>");
      %>
</div>
```

servlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setAttribute("image1", "None.png");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25621634/4549213
И сразу совет: не стоит использовать скриптлеты на страницах! Это неэффективно. А с версии сервлетов 3 на jsp можно и методы у блинов вызывать.